# ReferenceError: jwreload is not defined (Dynamic routing in next.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

**pages/blog/[blogId].js**

I have just started learning next.js. While practicing dynamic route according to documentation getting this error "ReferenceError: jwreload is not defined". Mysteriously the dynamic route I have created is accessible and this error dose not crushes the app but each time I reload it pops up in the browser, I can even find the parameter in dynamic route but this error dose not go away.

**next.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "dynamic-next",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.3.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.25.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.3.1"
  }
}
```

[image: This is the file structure in vs code]
[image: This is the err in browser]

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example on Stackblitz?

Comment: @vighnesh153 Here's the StackBlitz- https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-tlxgsp?file=pages/blog/[blogId].js

Surprisingly here in the StackBlitz I am not getting this err! What's wrong with my vs code :(

Comment: Try deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and run `npm install` and then finally run `npm run dev`

Comment: @vighnesh153 I have just tried this and did not worked :(

Comment: Please share your package.json and next.config.js files, as well, in the question to investigate further

Comment: @vighnesh153 I have added package.json and next.config.js files also.

Comment: This is strange. I tried to repro this on stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-adlqde?file=pages%2Fblog%2F[blogId].js) but couldn't do it. Would it be possible for you to just delete the entire project and re-create another one? Make sure to copy your source files first. Not something I would recommend doing always, but looks like something is wrong with the workspace.

Comment: @vighnesh153 I have also tried by creating new project but seems to be same :(

Comment: Found it, I was trying to reach the dynamic route from the browser manually but when I use next <Link></Link> the err disappeared.

Thank you so much @vighnesh153

Comment: Great. What do you mean by "reach the dynamic route from browser, manually"?

Comment: @vighnesh153 I was trying to get into the dynamic route by typing the URL in browser, but when i use the Link component to visit the dynamic route the error disappeared.

Comment: Manually typing the url in browser should work. That is the point of urls because you can share them and manually type/paste them in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I also had the same problem, same error.

The error was caused by an extension in the browser. In my case, it was GDPlay

[image]

If the problem persists, try removing or disabling any other suspicious extension causing this problem. Or else you could keep the error appearing. Either way your program could still work.

The way I found this is that I had a different error while accessing another page. The error was related to ajax, PHP. Also the problem disappears when I used a different browser profile, which then I assume any extension was the cause.